# Cygwin64 installed while MKS Toolkit was present

Tags: cygwin, mks

Has anyone done this and what was the result? I did this after turning off MKS at the service level. However, after doing all of the steps to install cygwin64 it now opens with the windows command prompt instead of the cygwin shell. I have tried everything I can find to set this correctly but nothing has worked. It defaults to C:/users/whatever. I did not get the home directory after opening cygwin.bat I can run cygwin but it uses CMD prompt controls and that is not really acceptable. I tried copying .bashrc to the home folder it gave me and all I get is ~ as the home I made a correct C:/cygwin64/home/user directory and put all the needed files in place such as .bashrc and .bashrc_profile etc. but I still do not get what is needed. Uninstalled MKS and reinstalled cygwin and it made no difference. Looking for some advice or pointers if any. I looked at ../etc/nsswitch.conf and it looks the same as all of the good cygwin installs I have done. I tried deleting the user environment variable HOME and no change. I aimed that variable to the c:cygwin64/home/user folder and no change. My system environment variable match exactly to how I have them on a good install. when i source .bashrc it does not find it.

Comment: have you used the installed Cygwin Terminal in the start menu ? It provides a better control than CMD used by Cygwin.bat .

Comment: _it now opens with the windows command prompt_ : I don't understand the meaning of this. Cygwin by itself does not 'open'  anything, and there is no "Cygwin Terminal". You have of course some terminal program (I'm using `mintty` BTW, but there are others too) and configure it to open a Cygwin shell of my liking (in my case _zsh_). If you need help in configuring your terminal´, you need to specify at least which one you use, and how it is currently configured.

Comment: If I were to double click bash.exe from the bin folder it will open in a windows cmd prompt not a shell. If I try to run mintty I get an error because it cannot find .bashrc I assume. I will try and point it to a correct terminal and see what I get. Thanks